# How to do the "light up the wireframe effect"

Tags: rendering, animation, lighting, wireframe

I want to make an effect similar to the one seen in this music video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrZC1Jcv0dw
I want an object to be completely black and then animate it's wireframe lighting up.
Maybe I can somehow achieve this by moving a cube through my object and making it light up where the cube intersects with the object.

EDIT to clarify: 
The effect I want is seen in 0:28 in this video when the gray lines start lighting up with blue glow.
I created a little visualization in paint to describe it better:
[image]

So the black thing is the 3D model that I am working with.
The orange square is an invisable cube that doesn't show up in a render.
And the red lines show the lit up wireframe.

So what I want to create is an invisible cube that moves along the axes and where it intersects with the 3D model (black), the wireframe lights up. So I create an effect that looks like the wireframe is slowly lighting up.

Anyone knows how this can be done?

Comment: I think a duplicated cube with a Wireframe Modifier and an Emitter Shader could do the job.

Comment: That would just make a glowing wireframe of a cube...

Comment: Hello, emission as volume with material offset on the wireframe modifier in cycles with volumetric environment would be a start, but it would be  helpful to others if you specified precisely what element of this video you wish to replicate by adding an image or two or even a timestamp in the video.

Comment: The easiest way to go about this is 3D Masks. Generate objects on a second renderlayer, render them white on a black background, use them as masks for a glow effect. 
A more direct (although not necessarily easier) approach would be light path node. Give your invisible cube a transparent shader and toy around with the transparent depth count.